# SweetAlert box not open

Tags: java, css, alert, box

I have downloaded the files .css and .js and add in my directory.
In this way I see only a simple button "Title" in my page.

```
<!-- BEGIN: MAIN VIEWER PAGE -->

<if="$mmhclass->templ->templ_globals['new_file_rating'] == true">
    <# NEW_RATING_HTML #><hr />
</endif>

<div class="text_align_center">
    <if="$mmhclass->funcs->is_null($mmhclass->input->get_vars['is_random']) == false">
        <a href="index.php?do_random=1" class="button1">New Random Image</a>
        <br /><br />
    </endif>
    <script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick='sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!" , "error")'>Title</button>
```

In this way I see nothing:

```
<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
swal({   title: "Error!",   text: "Here's my error message!",   type: "error",   confirmButtonText: "Cool" });
```

I'm editing a .tpl page. Where I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have all the files downloaded.

if downloaded, Try to place it in a folder and change src path for eg:(sweetalert.min.js,sweetalert.cs) in the main page,if necessary

Check browser compatibility.

After that you getting this same problem ,Please inform.

Regds..

Comment: I add files in a different folder and now works. :D  But the alert start when I press a button. For start it automatic?

Answer (score 0):

For invoke an alert box automatically after loading your web page

1st clear onclick() function of button1 and copy the same function to body onload event,like this.

```
<body onload='sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!" , "error")'>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this now:        <script type="text/javascript">
sweetAlert("Adult Content - Over 18?");
 window.open(
  'https://',
  '_blank' //
);
</script>      But the link not open clicking on OK but together with alert box.

Comment: var redirectWindow = window.open('http://page.com', '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location;                    try it

Comment: Works in this way:   function(){
    window.location.href = 'login.html';
       });       But for open in a new window?  If I add '_blank' not works. Maybe I wrong syntax.

Comment: Finally works in this way:  function(){
    window.open('login.html');
       });                   THANKS!